# Remote web application debugging not working in ios 8 beta

Tags: xcode, debugging, safari, ios8

I am trying to debug a web application under ios 8 beta on a simulator. Running the latest version of safari (Version 7.0.6) and Xcode, but all I am able to see is "No Inspectable Applications" in safari.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: IIRC, no Apple Beta products may be discussed outside of the beta forum community.

Answer (score 4):

You need the latest nightly build of Safari. Get it here:

http://nightly.webkit.org

Comment: A release for Mac was released yesterday that contained a new version of Safari and iOS 8 is now released. This should work. It must now be a bug on Apple's end :/

Comment: in addition to use the webkit nightly build you need to clear your browser data in your mobile safari settings. That did the trick for me.

i'm using the currently released ios8