# iOS 8 and Mac OS X 10.10 safari remote debuging

Tags: ios, macos, safari

I am attempting to remote debug from safari in Mac OS X 10.10 to monitor ajax requests. I can usually get the first network request, but then after that I don't get anything else. Has anyone had any issues with Safari remote debugging not working as it should?

Comment: Same problem here with iOS 8 general release. I have 10.8.5 and safari 6.1.6. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I haven't found a fix yet.

Comment: I can't even open the developer console. Keeps telling me No Inspectable Application. iOS 8, Safari 7.0.6 on Mac OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: And this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245575/remote-web-application-debugging-not-working-in-ios-8-beta   Need their nightly build and it works fine for me

Answer (score 2):

OK. I found the answer at apple developer community. You have to install and run the latest nightly webkit build

http://nightly.webkit.org/

You will be able to inspect web apps remotely.